# rails 3: trying to COUNT/GROUP on multiple fields, but getting SQL error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, count, group-by

My table StoreCodes holds unique products codes (and their availablity) for each store, eg:

```
category:integer
code:string
available:boolean
store_id:reference
```

I'm trying to show a simple table with 3 columns showing how many codes are in each category, AND how many of those codes have available = true

```
Category_number / Count_Codes_in_category / Count_Codes_in_category_available==TRUE
```

In my controller, the following attempt to COUNT and GROUP on both `category` and `available` throws this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "WHERE": syntax error: SELECT category, available, COUNT(*) AS instances GROUP BY category, available WHERE (store_id = 8)
```

My controller code:

```
@b2 = StoreCode.find_by_sql ['SELECT category, available, COUNT(*) AS instances GROUP BY category, available WHERE (store_id = ?)', @store.id]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is wrong. You have to put the `GROUP BY` clause after the `WHERE` clause, and when using `find_by_sql` you also need to write the complete statement (include the `FROM`clause)

Like this:

```
@b2 = StoreCode.find_by_sql ['SELECT category, available, COUNT(*) AS instances 
FROM store_codes WHERE (store_id = ?) GROUP BY category, available', @store.id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement has no 'FROM' clause, I also think the 'GROUP BY' should come after the 'WHERE'.